# What is this Java method doing?

Tags: java, dictionary, methods, keyset

```
public Map mystery(Map map1, Map map2) {
Map result = new TreeMap();
for (String s1 : map1.keySet()) {
    if (map2.containsKey(map1.get(s1))) {
        result.put(s1, map2.get(map1.get(s1)));
    }
}
return result;
}
```

map1={bar=1, baz=2, foo=3, mumble=4}; map2={1=earth, 2=wind, 3=air, 4=fire}

Comment: I don't need the answer to the problem, but if I could understand what the method is doing it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each key in map1 method looks at the corresponding value and of this value exists as a key in map2 than puts it a new TreeMap.

Consider one iteration. map1 has key `bar` and it's value is `1`. Now map2 has `1` as it's key with value `earth`. So data that is put in new Map is `bar:earth` and so on..

Also note since resultant map is a `TreeMap` elements will be stored in Lexicographical order (Since keys are Strings and TreeMap stores elements in sorted order as per keys natural ordering).

Answer (score 0):

It's calculating the composition of the functions `map2(map1)`, along with giving you an impressive number of raw-type warnings.